# 'Find an item' search only matches some sub-strings in multi-line text field

Tags: 2013, list, search

I have a list in a SharePoint Online site, which contains a multi-line rich text field. The list item I'm interested in contains a HTML table, the first column of which consists of strings like `AB4701`, `AB4702`, `AB4703` and `AB4704`.

When I search for `AB47*` in the *Find an item* search box at the top of the list, my list item appears in the results, as expected. The same is true if I search for `AB4701` or `AB4702`, but not for `AB4703` and `AB4704`. The list item doesn't appear in these last two searches.

The strings I'm searching for appear only in the field I mentioned, and checking the HTML confirms there aren't any invisible characters in the table that would cause the search not to match.

Why is it that the search matches one part of the field but not another?

Comment: I think your problem can be caused by the search column limit in the search index. I'll try to dig a bit further with your problem, will notify you if had success.

Comment: @RustamIsmagilov, did you find out any more about this, or whether the search column limit can be changed?